# Django passing value from template to view

Tags: python, django, web

I'm having trouble passing values from my template to view. Basically I created a form for user registration, and want to pass the values from the template to view so that I can construct a User object to add to my database. But somehow my "input" is not working when I add `name={{user_form.username}}`. Also, I want to pass values 0,1,2 respectively when I select "borrower", "libarrian" and "clerk", what can I do to implement this?

Below are my codes.

```
      <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/sign_up/" class="form-signin" role="form">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Signup </h2>

            {% if error%}

        <div class="error"> Your registration has been unsuccessfull </div> 
        {% endif %}

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{user_form.username}}" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Password" value="" required>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Retype password" value="" required>       


        <select class="form-control">
  <option value="2">Librarian</option>
  <option value="0">Borrower</option>
  <option value="1">Clerk</option>
</select>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

      </form>
```

In **forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

In **views.py**

```
   def sign_up(request):
    registered = False;
    error = False;
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            registered = True
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, None, password)
            user.save()
        else:
            error = True;
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'books/sign_up.html',
                  {'user_form':user_form,
                   'registered':registered, 'error':error})
```

Comment: Can you provide the template rendering line - how do you pass the form object to the template?

Comment: I never heard any `input` control with type `username`.. is this a type or you named it like this?

Answer (score 1):

Below form should work.

```
<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/sign_up/" class="form-signin" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Signup </h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"  value="{{user_form.username}}" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="Retype password" required>      
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Librarian</option>
        <option value="0">Borrower</option>
        <option value="2">Clerk</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Changes I have done are -

1. Change the names of username and password textboxes
2. Change the type for username textbox
3. Added value attribute in select control

Comment: Why would changing to name="username" pass the value to user_form.username?

Comment: Value should be passed to `value` attribute. Now edited my answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. You never mentioned value attribute above.

Comment: please refresh your screen

Comment: This didn't work. After adding value="{{user_form.username}}", my signup page simply had " placeholder="Username" required autofocus>  outside the input box.

Comment: No I don't find any problem in the updated HTML.. it should work. I copy pasted the same HTML in my code and it is not showing any error.

Comment: I simply deleted value="{{user_form.username}}" and it worked... weird, I don't understand why... Also, do you know how to define a select field in forms.py as my select above?

Comment: Your `user_form` is Form instance so it should not be in value. The data in forms are populated through `name` attribute, so you should name your forms according to your Form class

Comment: "so you should name your forms according to your Form class".. like how?

Comment: '<input name="username" />' basically `username` should be your form class attribute. Also if you donot have any styling thing `{{user_form.username}}` will render you input box in html template according to your Form class definition.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/